# Using JQuery Mask Plugin to only aloud numbers (can't start with 0)

Tags: jquery, plugins, masking

I have this input (and i'm using JQuery Mask Plugin):

```
 <input type="text" name="number" class="campo-formulario mascara-end-numero campo-numero perfil-input" id="perfil-numero" placeholder="Numero">
```

Which can only accept numbers, and the first number CAN'T be 0.

Using this, only numbers are accepted:

```
jQuery('.mascara-end-numero').mask('#');
```

Tried to define the "non-zero-at-first" rule using:

```
jQuery('.mascara-end-numero').mask('Z#', {
            translation: {
              'Z': {
                pattern: /[1-9]/, optional: true
              }
            }
          });
```

But it didn't work :/

How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution (remove "optional"):

```
jQuery('.mascara-end-numero').mask('Z#', {
            translation: {
              'Z': {
                pattern: /[1-9]/
              }
            }
          });
```